# Changing Android actionbar title text with editText gettext

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to change the actionbar title text to whatever is typed in the editText view how would I go about doing this?

So far I have this:

````
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

       editTextHouse = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_house);

       ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle(editTextHouse);
       String title = actionBar.getTitle().toString(); ```
````

Comment: you want edittext in a place of action bar or you want to set the text of actionbar text with the text of editext

Comment: I want to set the text of actionbar with the text of edittext

Comment: on Button click or on text change ??/??

Comment: on button click

Comment: ok so here is how you can set on button click I answered it

Comment: if you want to change it by clicking button, just change your code like this --> getSupportActionBar().setTitle(yourEditText.getText().toString()); and add this which button onClick events you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello there you can try this with Button Click

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stack);

    Button buttonClick = findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    final EditText editTextData = findViewById(R.id.editTextData);

    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //this require non null for null string crash  
          Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(editTextData.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: My pleasure pal

Comment: If I wanted to change the title of another activity using that input how would I go about doing that?

Comment: want to change another activity title from another activity ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well. I want to set all my activities actionbars to the one i edit

Comment: Here is two three way to do that, but we have to make sure that which one is best practice right

1st you can create one constant value like static variable that store your value and then you can set title text after in every activity's oncreate method right after setcontent view. 

if you think it is not better way. 

you can use mvvm pattern and then set live data through it is up to you how you wan to achieve it !

Answer (score 0):

On Edittext textChang actionBar title will be changed, Try this.

```
editTextHouse .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // Do some thing now
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // Do something at this time
              if (s != null && s.length() > 0) 
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s.toString());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use getSupportActionBar().setTitle(editTextHouse.getText()); for what you are doing